# How to sync a local email storage to IMAP (mutt-friendly)?

Tags: email, mutt, fetchmail, imap

### Summary

**My problem**: I want to read email offline with my choice of client (`mutt`), but I want actions like moving emails, etc. to be kept in two-way snc with an imap server.

**My question**: Is there a straightforward way to do this while still using standard tools like `fetchmail`, `procmail`, etc.?

### Details

I have a gmail account. For various reasons - some institutional - I need to be able to read this mail from a mail client; I want my 'inbox' to be clean, much like I would keep it with a traditional local mail setup, and for anything I 'archive' to be searchable. If I move an email to a folder in the web client, I'd like my local inbox to take this into account.

When possible, I want  to be able to read this mail from `mutt`. Previously I used mutt's native imap functionality, but mutt has to make a connection to the server each time you run it; the connection often drops while I'm reading mail and mutt is open in the background; it only keeps a cache of message headers, and loading new messages requires a round-trip to the server; if I send a message, I have to wait for it to be acknowledged over STMP before I can look at any other messages.

Is there some way around this? I don't consider fat clients like Thunderbird to be a solution: I require terminal access, I like to be able to grep my mail, I make good use of procmail's filtering capabilities, and I prefer decoupled systems.

As mentioned above, `fetchmail`, `procmail` and `sendmail` get me  *almost* there - but not quite to being able to keep my activity in sync between clients.

Am I missing something? I've looked at the FreeBSD handbook's section on email and a bunch of blog posts but nothing seems to bring it all together in this way.

By the way, I run Arch Linux and Debian.

Comment: Have you considered `offlineimap` or `isync`? They both work well...

Comment: Just to help out @jasonwryan's comment: http://offlineimap.org/ & http://isync.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. I found isync, now named absync. It's working well!

Comment: I like Alpine e-mail for this purpose, if that helps.

Answer (score 10):

[OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org/) and [isync](http://isync.sourceforge.net/) are both programs that integrate well with `mutt` and will satisfy your other criteria.

OfflineIMAP is written in Python and isync in C; both are very quick.

Both programs are well documented and straightforward to set up; isync perhaps slightly easier.

<strike>There is one significant difference between the functionality of each that is worth bearing in mind: you can use `mbsync` (isync's executable) to repopulate a remote IMAP maildir<sup>1</sup> from a local copy, OfflineIMAP cannot do this.</strike> [Amendment: from v6.4.0, OfflineIMAP has the [createfolders](http://www.offlineimap.org/doc/nametrans.html#createfolders) option to create folders on the remote repository].

The Arch Wiki has pages on both, with example configurations and use cases.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1. In the event, hypothetically, you inadvertently delete your remote mail store and need to recover from a backup on a local machine...</sup>
<sup>2. [isync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Isync) and [OfflineIMAP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Offlineimap).</sup>

Comment: I second the isync/mbsync idea. OfflineImap is not reliable enough for me with my Gmail account (I'm subscribed to several high-traffic mailing lists and OfflineImap was getting stuck very often).

Comment: The stated difference does not seem to hold true anymore (for OfflineIMAP, see: [createfolder](http://docs.offlineimap.org/en/latest/nametrans.html#createfolders)) ?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Yes: this was introduced in 6.4.0. I'll update my answer, thanks for the prompt.

Comment: On-Off topic: another difference is that `mbsync` can't handle UTF8 stuff, while there is a Python solution for `offlineimap` (see [Greek characters in mutt's sidebar](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140900/13011) for example. Wish `mbsync` could do it, or I'll try to offer a Python based solution for it as well, if possible. OfflineIMAP's give's me problems lately (UID validity related, as well as creating duplicate messages once I remove the `readonly = true` option.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/the-homely-mutt/#getting-email excellently written post from Steve Losh will help you

Comment: It would be better to repeat the relevant parts of the information the link provides here and use the link as a reference for more detail. That way your answer stays useful even if the link goes away at some point.