# Mutt index disappearing on IMAP reconnect

Tags: mutt, imap

`Mutt` IMAP is working just fine ... until IMAP server drops the connection.

Then `mutt` automatically reconnects to the server - also just fine, according to the messages in the  status line - but! **it clears the list of messages in its index screen** upon reconnect and requires manual reentry into the mailbox to regenerate the message list, which is virtually equal to a `mutt` restart!

Happens with all IMAP servers I tried: Gmail, Dovecot, CyrusIMAP.

This is a major annoyance especially when you have done a big selection of messages for a group operation and suddenly you have start all over.

Or am I perhaps missing something? May it be that `mutt` doesn't reconnect really, gives misleading status messages and I need a [`mutt next generation`](http://mutt-ng.berlios.de/)?

Comment: Mutt's IMAP performance has always been flaky, you are probably better off using another application like [OfflineIMAP or isync](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72369/local-email-storage-syncing-to-imap-mutt-friendly) to manage that for Mutt...

Comment: @jasonwryan for syncing with offlineimap for example, it's necessarto have anough disk space for your full mailbox; that may complicate things. I like that mutt only downloads some messages and keeps them in the cache. it would be good it there was a way to just reconnect properly when imap connection goes down...